# Example of working iOS project using XSD/e

Tags: ios

I want to use the (looks to be) excellent LibXSD/e library from here: http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsde/

I have followed the guide to building the binary .a file and the wiki and README files on setting everything up. However I continue to run into problem after problem trying to compile after linking to the binary and getting the cxx/hxx files from an xsd-source.

From things like not finding string or iterator, dozens of other stl-errors..... i am happy to post them here but what I would really like is a working iOS example project if someone has one. Something I can just open in Xcode and hopefully see where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Four things to be done:

- Rename your files to .mm extension so they are c++ compatible where you include the generated pimp and pskel files
- Add libXSDE as a framework
- Add XSDE header path to Build Settings => Header Search Paths
- Switch C lang dialiect to C99, C++ language dialect to Compiler default and C++ lang Standard library to Compiler default

Nice tutorial can be found here: http://amateuritsolutions.blogspot.hu/2012/10/validate-xsd-schema-in-your-ios.html